# Bundling third party scss files into angular library created using angular-cli

Tags: angular, sass, angular-cli, angular-library

I have created a angular library using **angular-cli** this has the further dependency on [materialize-css](http://materializecss.com/getting-started.html). So I have mentioned `materialize-css` as `peerDependencies` in **projects/lib-name/package.json**.

Now as there is no direct support for global scss so I am using `scss-bundle` to bundle all the scss files into one and then copy the file into the **dist** folder of the library.

The structure for scss files

```
projects/lib-name/src/lib/sass/
   /common/_materialize-css.scss (this imports some of component's scss from materialize-css library)
   /lib-name.scss
```

and **lib-name.scss** imports **/common/_materialize-css.scss**

This is the script I have created in app's **package.json**

```
"watch-scss": "scss-bundle -e \"./projects/lib-name/src/lib/sass/lib-name.scss\" -d \"./dist-lib/lib-name/sass/lib-name.scss\" -w \"./projects/lib-name/src/lib/sass\""
```

But this is not resolving `materialize-css` scss files and showing the error

```
common\node_modules\materialize-css\sass\components\variables.scss [NOT FOUND]

lib-name.scss
[watch-scss] ├─┬ common\_materialize.scss
[watch-scss] │ ├── common\node_modules\materialize-css\sass\components\color-variables.scss [NOT FOUND]
[watch-scss] │ ├── common\node_modules\materialize-css\sass\components\variables.scss [NOT FOUND]
[watch-scss] │ ├── common\node_modules\materialize-css\sass\components\normalize.scss [NOT FOUND]
[watch-scss] │ ├── common\node_modules\materialize-css\sass\components\buttons.scss [NOT FOUND]
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**lib-name.scss**

```
@import "./common/variables.scss";
@import "./common/materialize-config.scss";
@import "./common/materialize.scss";
```

**/common/materialize.scss**

```
@import "~materialize-css/sass/components/color-variables";
@import "~materialize-css/sass/components/variables";
@import "~materialize-css/sass/components/normalize";
```

As app and library share the same **node_modules** so I need to install the **materialize-css** library as well. I was just mentioning it in the lib's **package.json** (one that is going to publish).

As this is the main dependency so instead of mentioning it in `peerDependencies`, I mentioned it under the `dependencies`

```
{
  "name": "my-lib",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "materialize-css": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^7.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^7.1.0"
  }
}
```

if you want to define `dependencies` then you need to white list this in **ng-package.json** (one that ng-packager uses while building the library) like this

```
{
  "$schema": "../../node_modules/ng-packagr/ng-package.schema.json",
  // ----- 
  "whitelistedNonPeerDependencies": [
    "materialize-css"
  ]
}
```

to run watch mode with scss-bundle install the latest version using

```
yarn add scss-bundle@next -D
```

Answer (score -1):

change your angular.json file

```
"schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "styleext": "css"
        }
      },
```

replace with

```
"schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "styleext": "scss"
        }
      },
```

and import your scss file in styles array

```
"styles": [                  
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
```

Comment: I want to bundle in the the library